# Where do I find Galasoft.MvvmLight.WPF45 assembly?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I'm using VS2013 Express. I'm quite new in WPF and MVVM. I've downloaded mvvmlight using NuGet to my project. I'm tryinng to use `GalaSoft_MvvmLight_Command:EventToCommand`. As far as I know, I have to add reference in xaml by adding namespace:

```
xmlns:GalaSoft_MvvmLight_Command="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight"
```

But, unfortunatelly I get error, that says:

> The tag 'EventToCommand' does not exist in XML namespace
>   'clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight'.

I've found some information, that I have to include `GalaSoft.MvvmLight.WPF45` assembly, but I don't see this dll in packages\MvvmLightLibs.5.0.0.1\lib\ folder. There are many folders, for each .NET version etc, but each of these assemblies names are the same, without WPF45 sufix.What is going on? Where do I find this GalaSoft.MvvmLight.WPF45.dll assembly? Or maybe in version 5 was some changes made in names?

Edit:
Using object browser I found that `EventToCommand` is in GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Platform assembly in GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command namespace. So I did

```
xmlns:GalaSoft_MvvmLight_Command="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Platform"
```

I can compile project now, but I still get errors in xaml (what is weird):

> A value of type 'EventToCommand' cannot be added to a collection or dictionary of type 'TriggerActionCollection'

and

> The type 'EventToCommand' from assembly 'GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Platform' is built with an older version of the Blend SDK, and is not supported in a Windows Presentation Framework 4 project.

and xaml editor can't display window properly (invalid markup).

Edit2:

## Solution for invalid markup.

After I've changed the namespace to `xmlns:cmd="http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvmlight"` I also change project's target framework from 4.5 to 3.5. IDE shows an error about there are few NuGet packages that target other framework, so I returned to 4.5 - and it magically works now ;). Thanks all for help.

Comment: Try this. xmlns:cmd="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Platform". You also need [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Expression.Blend.Sdk/) nuget package

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how its done now in your XAML assuming you've got Version 4.0.0. Beat 1 or higher:

xmlns:cmd="http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvmlight"

I found this at the bottom the release notes here: http://www.mvvmlight.net/installing/changes/

Details
XmlnsDefinitionAttribute for GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command in Extras assembly

Thanks to the addition of XmlnsDefinitionAttribute, you can simplify the inclusion of the MVVM Light EventToCommand action in XAML. See the before and after below:

Before:

```
<UserControl xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"

xmlns:cmd="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.SL4"

xmlns:cmd="http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvmlight"
x:Class="MvvmLight4.MainPage">
```

After:

```
<UserControl xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
xmlns:cmd="http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvmlight"
x:Class="MvvmLight4.MainPage">
```

Comment: I've changed namespaces, but still getting error with older version. But thanks, it works now fine.

Comment: Didn't work for me with WPF 4.5 - Still getting the same error!

Comment: Did not make a jot of difference.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

`EventToCommand` exists in the `Extras` assembly.

Try:

```
xmlns:GalaSoft_MvvmLight_Command="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras"
```

---

**More Information:**

To determine the assembly a class falls in, I usually *Go To Definition* and the assembly is referenced in the region at the top of the *[from metadata]* code file.

Comment: Tried this as well in a WPF 4.5.2, and as @BartoszRosa, I get `EventToCommand` does not exist in namespace and a second error i.e. EventToCommand does not exists.